# vs2013 winforms project does not work on other computers giving filenotfound exception

Tags: c#, winforms, xsd, app-config

I am new at visual studio,forgive me if this is an easy issue to solve.

I have developed a winforms application with vs2013 and used some webservices.
My problem is when i deploy my project to another computer which have no any visual studio versions installed,gives me System.IO.FileNotFound error.
Recently i realized that my app.config file's schemas property has some paths like

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig45.xsd"
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\xml\Schemas\EntityFrameworkConfig_6_1_0.xsd"
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\xml\Schemas\RazorCustomSchema.xsd"
>
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft\VisualStudio\XMLEditor\ServiceModel.93d9284583274f8c9f8ff31f2dd0cb96.xsd"

The problem is other computers don't have these paths.
Also i try to select 'do not use this schema' option but whenever i build or run my project,visual studio ignores my seelction.
What is the problem? Why do i get this error?Are there any general issues that i need to know?
I searched and could not find any solution to this.

Comment: The FileNotFoundException is not related to those schemas, they're only used at development time for IntelliSense and validation. Log and inspect the actual exception, and you'll see which file you actually forgot to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
It is not about those xsd files.Visual studio did not include a .dll file that my project used.I solved this issue by installing visual studio to client machine and ran the project directly from visual studio and then gave me exact name of missing .dll file.After including the .dll file now my project works fine.